# Efficient way to end the recursion?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to define a recursive function that returns X if the given input's square sum leads to 1, which works fine. However, if the input doesn't lead to 1 then it keeps looping and I cannot find a way to exit it.

For instance, input of integer 7, 10, 13 leads to 1, but input of 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 11 does not. If I try
`x === 4 || x === 0`
, it ends the recursion for the input that does not lead to 1 but for some inputs it takes multiple recursion calls to reach to 4 and that's not efficient. Later on, I want to use the return values for other calculations.

```
function recursion(x) {
  if (x === 0) {
    return;
  }

  if (x === 1) {
    return x;
  }

  x = squareSum(x);
  return recursion(x);
}
```

Here is the squareSum function.

```
function sqaureSum(n){
    let sumTotal;

    if (n < 10){
        sumTotal = Math.pow(n, 2);
        return sumTotal;

    }

    sumTotal = Math.pow(n % 10, 2) + squareSum(Math.floor(n / 10));
    return sumTotal;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I just edited the post with correction. It's the same function sumSqaure calling itself.

Comment: Yes. Initially I had x === 4 || x === 0 as the first condition. Because sumSqaure of any input, that doesn't lead to 1, at some point was reaching 4. But as I mentioned, for some inputs, it was taking multiple recursion calls to reach to 4.

Comment: I don't see either `recursion` or `squareSum` producing the problem you describe. `recursion` produces a stack overflow for all inputs other than 0 and 1, and `squareSum` does not produce an endless loop in the cases of 5, 11, etc.

Comment: maybe you can track the previous answer and compute the next answer, if both of them are the same, then you can stop the recursion as a failure

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar for input 11 it takes 2 recursion to reach 4. For input 30 it takes 9 calls. So, I'm trying to seek efficient way to end the recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to track the numbers you've already seen, stopping when you reach `1` or when you reach a number you've already seen.

We can add a default parameter with a list of already-seen numbers, and then in a recursive call, add the current number to that list.  This version just returns a boolean, `true` if the number eventually reaches `1` and `false` if we hit some other cycle.  And we find the numbers among the first hundred positive integers, which do reduce to `1`:

```js
const squareSum = (n) => 
  (n) < 10 ? n * n : (n % 10) ** 2 + squareSum (Math .floor ( n / 10))

const repeatedSquareSum = (n, seen = []) => 
  n <= 1 
    ? true
  : seen .includes (n) 
    ? false
  : repeatedSquareSum (squareSum (n), [...seen, n])

console .log (Array .from ({length: 100}, (n, i) => i + 1) .filter (n => repeatedSquareSum(n)))
```

You wanted to return the original number in the positive case.  That's odd, but not much more difficult:

```js
const repeatedSquareSum = (n, seen = []) => 
  n <= 1 
    ? seen [0] || n
  : seen .includes (n) 
    ? false
  : repeatedSquareSum (squareSum (n), [...seen, n])
```

(The `|| n` bit is just because we haven't yet added anything to `seen` in the cases of `0` and `1`.)

You also could return the array of numbers visited in the false case, by returning `seen` instead of `false` in that case, or if you just want to see the repeating cycle of numbers, you could return `[...seen .slice (seen.indexOf (n)), n]`.

Other notes have pointed out that there is only one cycle of repeating values, outside of `0 -> 0` and `1 -> 1`.  And that is `4 -> 16 -> 37 -> 58 -> 89 -> 145 -> 42 -> 20 -> 4`.  This somewhat surprising result is proven in a fairly readable [formal mathematical paper](https://fermatslibrary.com/s/a-set-of-eight-numbers).  Using that information, we can choose to write an even simpler version:

```js
const repeatedSquareSum = (n) =>
  n <= 1 
    ? true 
  : n == 4 
    ? false 
  : repeatedSquareSum (squareSum (n))
```

### Update

A followup question in the comments (next time, please start a new question) asked how to count the number of steps until we reach a target number such as `20`.  We can add a default parameter with the `count`, and track until we reach that number or enter a loop.  The only complexity is that if the target is in the list of numbers that cycle endlessly, we need to not stop when we enter the loop but only when we hit the target number.

Here we build this on the last version above for simplicity, but we could also do so atop the earlier, more complex versions:

```js
const squareSum = (n) => 
  (n) < 10 ? n * n : (n % 10) ** 2 + squareSum (Math .floor ( n / 10))

const squareSumToTarget = (target) => (n, count = 0) =>
  n <= 1 || (![4, 16, 37, 58, 89, 145, 42, 20] .includes (target) && n == 4)
    ? Infinity
  : n == target 
    ? count 
  : squareSumToTarget (target) (squareSum (n), count + 1)

const squareSumTo20 = squareSumToTarget (20)
console .log (squareSumTo20 (445566)) //=> 3 (445566 -> 154 -> 42 -> 20)
console .log (squareSumTo20 (44)) //=> Infinity (44 -> 32 -> 13 -> 10 -> 1 -> 1 -> 1 -> ...)
console .log (squareSumTo20 (4)) //=> 7 (4 -> 16 -> 37 -> 58 -> 89 -> 145 -> 42 -> 20)

console .log (squareSumToTarget (17) (79)) //=> Infinity (79 -> 130 -> 10 -> 1 -> 1 -> 1 -> ...) 
console .log (squareSumToTarget (36) (5) )
//=> Infinity (36 -> 45 -> 41 -> 17 -> 50 -> 25 -> 29 -> 85 -> 89 -> 145 -> 42 -> 20 -> 4 -> 16 -> 37 -> 58 -> 89 ...)
//                                                              ^----------------------------------------------'
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for. One more question though. How would you go about if you have to find an input that takes n number of squareSum executions to reach a certain  integer. For instance, how many times squareSum would be executed for an input of 30 to return 20. Or to be specific, how to find an input that takes 6 executions of squareSum to reach 20?

Comment: Updated to handle the new request.  Next time, instead, please open a new question if there are substantial differences.

Answer (score 0):

because of `sumTotal = Math.pow(n % 10, 2) + squareSum(n / 10);`
when you calculate `n / 10` it's can be a float, and you should convert your numbers to `int`

for checking `float` numbers log x inside `recursion`

```js
function recursion(x) {
  console.log(x) // <-- HERE
  ...
}
```

`Math.floor`, `Math.ceil`, `Math.round` can help you

and for

```js
  if (x === 0) {
    return;
  }
```

inside `recursion` add a value ( 0 or 1 ).
it's return `undefiend` and it convert to `NaN`

Comment: Yes. I fixed that with ```sumTotal = Math.pow(n % 10, 2) + squareSum(Math.floor(n / 10))```.

Comment: No. That was not what I was asking for. What I was asking for is to end the recursion as soon I can figure out that given number  will not lead to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Searching a few minuts, I found [this](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2018/03/24/squared-digit-sum/) util information. Summarizing, you can check if the number you get, in some point is equal to any of these numbers: 4, 16, 37, 58, 89, 145, 42, 20:

```
const loopNumbers = new Set([4, 16, 37, 58, 89, 145, 42, 20]);
...
if(loopNumbers.has(x)) {
  // It does not lead to 1
}
```